# In linux, how can I determine what processes are using a block device?

Tags: linux, lvm, partition

I have a disk in a server that I'm migrating to a LVM volume group.  Previously, it was using traditional DOS-disk partitioning, `hdb[1-5]`.

I've unmounted every filesystem from `hdb`, shut off swap using `hdb`, removed a smaller VG on the device already, and went to repartition it using fdisk, deleted existing partitions, and created 2 partitions, but upon writing it out, linux refused to re-read the partition table.  Trying again using `hdparm -z` reports: `BLKRRPART failed: Device or resource busy.`

I've checked the following places to ensure the device and it's partitions arn't listed anywhere:

- /proc/swaps
- /proc/mdadm
- output from 'pvs' command
- output from 'mount' command
- /etc/mtab
- lsof | grep hdb

But `cat /proc/partitions` still lists the partitioning, and `hdparm -z /dev/hdb` still gives me device busy.

Is there a something I'm missing, or a secret place I don't yet know about to find what's still holding on to my block device?  and more importantly, How can I release it's hold so I  can reload the partition table?

FWIW, on this specific case, I can simply reboot the server w/o much worry, but this has plagued me before, and I'm curious if there is a better way.

(Edit: added more precise wording)
(Edit: details re repartitioning)

Update: I used `partprobe /dev/hdb`, and it did change things: in /dev /hdb1, /deb/hdb[3-5] are now gone,  and partprobe is reporting `Error: Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition /dev/hdb1 -- Device or resource busy.` <-- specifically about hdb1.  hdb1 formerly was a Physical Volume (PV) in a LVM Volume Group (VG), abut i vgremove + pvremoved em before I repartitioned......

Update 2: FWIW, I still haven't corrected this problem, fortunatly it's not urgent.  I've learned that partprobe is using a newer API call which is why it did seem to do something earlier.  I still haven't found an simple and effective way to, given a device, and it's major/minor numbers, figure out which resources (kernel or userspace) are using it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check again with pvdisplay and vgdisplay if this partition is still assigned to any LVM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using fuser

```
fuser -vam /dev/hdb1
```

Comment: I tried fuser on /dev/hdb and /dev/hdb[1-5], and it's still reporting nothing using those devices.

Comment: FWIW, I never fully resolved this, but I've since restarted the machine, and that corrected it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`lsof` is the command you're looking for.  You'll normally want to pipe it to grep with the mount point.

Example
`lsof | grep var` will list all processes that have open files where the path or filename contains "var"

Comment: disregard my answer...I see that you did lsof at the bottom of your list....missed that when I answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

Eddy's `fuser -vam /dev/hdb1` example was essentially correct, but it lacked some completeness.  In my case, I ran into a similar problem while recovering files from someone off the last drive of a raid1 array where the partition holding the data was in LVM.

In this case, I had started `photorec` to examine the drive, seen that there was a volume group, and then closed the terminal running `photorec`.  Unbeknownst to me, `photorec` was still holding on to `/dev/mapper/vg0-lv0`.  So, in the future, try using `fuser`, but on the contents of `/dev/mapper/`

`fuser -vam /dev/mapper/*`

This still probably not the best answer, but remember to try to check against any files under /dev/ that might also map in some way to the block device you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of the command `mount`.  Not sure if this applies to your situation, but I know I have used [bind mounts](http://wiki.openvz.org/Bind_mounts) on several occasions.  Un-mounting the source filesystem from a bind-mount does not unmount bind mounts.  The output of mount isn't very useful in this case for letting you know what is going on.

Comment: mount | grep hdb doesn't list anything; mount | grep /oldmountpoint doesn't doesn't list anything under the old mount point, and only shows the new device @ the old mount point, that I had moved stuff to.  I was able to completely unmount it before the repartition, which indicates (to me at least) that there was nothing binding under it, and it wasn't bound elsewhere.